# Locate elements in a list tag with WebDriver

Tags: xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to loop through a list tag and collect all the elements and click on a particular item if it matches the given string.

The HTML code is:

```
<ul multiple="multiple" name="optionsTab" taborder="1" class="focus">
   <li value="2" selected="selected">option1</li>
   <li value="5" selected="selected">option2</li>
   <input id="form-3-input-5" name="optionsTab" type="hidden" value= "2,5">
</ul>
```

Java code:

```
webdriver1.findElement(By.xpath("//ul/li[1]")).click();
```

to directly click on option1 gives me an elementNotFoundException.

What is the best way to locate the li tag and access the list.

Comment: clean up your selector.  This will match `any` `<ul>`. you don't want that.  Instead, since you have a `name` attribute that can identify it, use that instead.  CSS: `ul[name='optionsTab'] > li` or xpath (ew): `//ul[@name='optionsTab']/li`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest case would be to find the list first `Webelemebt list = driver.findElement(By.name("optionsTab"));` and then find the elements within that list `List<Webelement> elements = list.findElements(By.xpath("//li"));`

Then you can iterate over each element within your collection to find the element that you want.

Comment: This solution works. There were empty text strings in the list that I had to escape in order to select all the available list items

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the below **XPATH**

```
 //ul[@name='optionsTab']/li[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use for instance the following CssSelector approach:

webdriver1.findElement(By.CssSelector("ul[name='optionsTab']>li[value='2']")).Click();

If you keep getting ElementNotFound exceptions are you sure this element has loaded yet? You could always try a wait for the element?